# Selecting N amount of MAX and MIN values from the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to select n amount of highest people and n amount of shortest people
people where the person is MALE. Height is stored in column named 'height' and gender is stored in column named accordingly (as F or M)

[image]

I tried something like this

```
select name,height from people where gender = 'M' order by height asc limit 5
```

Then I wanted to just somehow join the result of this and result of the same line but in descending order.

I also wonder if you could do this in other way.

I imagined result of this operation would look something like this

[image]

(height numbers are random but the paired columns on the lefr should contain the highest people and the paired columns on right the shortest)

I also tried something like this

```
(select name,height from people where gender = 'M' order by height desc limit 5) union (select name,height  from people where gender = 'M' order by height asc limit 5) order by height asc
```

But I don't like ther result since you don't have 2 columns separated as shortest and heighest instead it is all in 1 column and you need to manually count the n amount of people from the top to see which one are highest.

I am doing this in postgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two columns do not have overlaps, you can use a trick with two row numbers:

```
select max(name) filter (where seqnum_desc < seqnum_asc) as name_tall,
       max(height) filter (where seqnum_desc < seqnum_asc) as height_tall,
       max(name) filter (where seqnum_asc < seqnum_desc) as name_short,
       max(height) filter (where seqnum_asc < seqnum_desc) as height_short       
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by height asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by height desc) as seqnum_desc
      from people p
      where gender = 'M'
     ) p
where seqnum_asc <= 5 or seqnum_desc <= 5
group by least(seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=02477accec9601466f2981e429a2c41f) is a db<>fiddle.

As a note:  This should work in older versions:

```
select max(case when seqnum_desc < seqnum_asc then name end) as name_tall,
       max(case when seqnum_desc < seqnum_asc then height end ) as height_tall,
       max(case when seqnum_asc < seqnum_desc then name end) as name_short,
       max(case when seqnum_asc < seqnum_desc then height end) as height_short       
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by height asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by gender order by height desc) as seqnum_desc
      from people p
      where gender = 'M'
     ) p
where seqnum_asc <= 5 or seqnum_desc <= 5
group by least(seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me, it says there is a mistake in syntax near second  '(' just before where seqnum_desc
It's quite possible that i messed something up when changing name of columns but i dont think so

Comment: @antekkalafior . . . There is no such syntax error.  There was a typo in a column name, but I fixed that and added a fiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry Sir. It's hard for me to translate errors to english. It shows me the exact same error as before. Sadly I can't find the reason why it is not working. It's my fault but i dont know why

Comment: Maybe the reason is the version I forgot to mention. I use 8.4.20 and you did it in 13. I belive the "filter" expression was added in version 9

Comment: I am wondering too why we are learning on version 8. Unfortunatelly this is the way our lecturer runs his classes. I didn't down vote it because I simply can't do it (not enought rep). I will accept your answer because it clearly works on newer versions. Thank you for  help